# Appauth : Authorization error: State mismatch, expecting in Swift iOS

Tags: appauth

I have Azure Sign up & login page.
If I go to Sign in then it redirecting properly and Even If go sign up then also working.
But I I click on Sign up and click on Login page then below error come.

Authorization error: State mismatch, expecting vH41GKNSEXMSdZdG-J3qUK5gy-Y07A_C__qahCmbrbs but got (null) in authorization response <OIDAuthorizationResponse: 0x600001658410, authorizationCode: (null), state: "(null)", accessToken: "(null)", accessTokenExpirationDate: (null), tokenType: (null), idToken: "(null)", scope: "(null)", additionalParameters: {
}, request: <>>

Please help us if any has faced same issue.
I have used AppAuth pod for Azure authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The request may contain sensitive data (client ID), you should may not want to share it publicly.

The "state" parameter is provided in the request and is expected to be returned as is in the response. Here you have null, so AppAuth returns this error. However, as every field of the response is "null", I would say that the issue is elsewhere in your authentication setup and that the message is misleading.

I don't know much Azure authentication, I can't help you much!